# Is there a rigorous proof that $L_1$ regularization produces sparse results

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, convex-optimization, regularization

I'm looking for a rigorous proof that the $L_1$ regularization really produces sparsity, there are multiple intuitive ones [like these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)#Interpretations) which I understand but all of these feel like they just explain why coefficients shrink towards zero, not why they produce exact zero elements. Does this proof exist or is using the $L_1$ regularization just a heuristic approach to solve the $L_0$ regularization efficiently

Comment: There isn't a guarantee in general that your solution will be sparse - for lots of toy problems we can come up with, the solution could even be dense. The reason we solve the $\ell^1$ regularized problem is because the $\ell^1$ regularizer is the "closest" convex regularizer to the $\ell^0$ regularizer, which certainly induces sparsity.

Comment: Okay thats good to know, I thought there might be a something that follows from the convex regularization you could use to show that the solution will be sparse but your comment cleared it up, thanks

Comment: Consider the problem $\min\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{1}{2}\|x-y\|_2^2 + \lambda\|x\|_1$ where $y = [c, c]$ for some $c > 1$. You will always get a dense solution here for any $c > 0$, $\lambda>0$, even though it's $\ell^1$ regularized. This is because the problem is equivalent to $\min\limits_{x\in B_{\tilde{\lambda}}^1(0)}\frac{1}{2}\|x-y\|_2^2$ where $\tilde{\lambda}>0$ is a constant depending on $\lambda$ and $B_{\tilde{\lambda}}^1(0)$ is the $\ell^1$ ball of radius $\tilde{\lambda}$ centered at $0$. This is just the projection onto the ball, which is be dense for points like $[c,c]$.